# Is there colour picker in texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

Is there colour picker in texture paint mode? similar to photoshop or gimp

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can find the color picker by clicking on left or right Brush Color rectangles.

[image]

A faster way will be using <kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut to sample color under the cursor location in 3D window or UV/Image Editor.

Comment: Also note that you can quickly activate the color picker for any particular color field/swatch by pressing `E` while hovering over it.

Comment: note that the color dropper button will pick a color _from the screen_, NOT from the underlying texture!  `S` does pick from the texture (though it seems to get a bit confused by mirror modifiers)